# Issues with Journey Builder for Apps SDK for use with MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android, sdk, mobilepush-ios

We are implementing the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey Builder for Apps SDKs for use with MobilePush. (version 4.6.0 for Android and 4.2.1 for iOS) for our mobile app. We followed the integration based off the documentation and are having issues with the Alert + CloudPage option. The expected result is the ability to send a push notification and also have a message reside in our app's inbox. The issues we're seeing:

1. When sending a message to “Alert + CloudPage”, we receive the push notification and when clicked on, it does take us to the linked cloud page URL (which is correct). However, when we go back to the inbox, the message disappears and cannot be read again. We are not deleting the message but simply viewing it. If a user reads a message, does that automatically delete it? We are wanting the message to still reside, but be marked as unread.
2. If we don’t open the actual CloudPage message, it will still be shown in the Inbox of the app. We tested a scenario where we deleted 3 messages in the Inbox, deleted and re-installed the app and all the deleted messages appear back in the Inbox. Is correct behavior?

Answer (score 0):

1. The CloudPageAdapter has a method which allows you to decide which messages should be displayed: `setDisplay(CloudPageListAdapter.DISPLAY_UNREAD)`  You may pass in `DISPLAY_READ`, `DISPLAY_UNREAD` and `DISPLAY_ALL`.
2. The state of the messaging is stored in the SDK.  If you uninstall the application and re-install it you will lose all existing message read/unread state.

Expanding answer to address comment.

1. What version of the SDK are you using?  There was an issue previously that prevented old, expired messages from being deleted.  Versions 4.3.1 and 4.4.0 both addressed similar, but different issues with regards to CloudPages and their lifecycle on the device.  See [RELEASE NOTES](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/) for details.

If we need to dig any deeper you're going to need to open a formal escalation with your account manager as we'd want to dig into the specifics of your MID and the message details.